# Universal elements of a functor and representability

Tags: category-theory, yoneda-lemma, representable-functor

A functor $F : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{Set}$ is said to *representable* if it is naturally isomorphic to $\mathcal{C}(A,–)$ for some object $A$ of $\mathcal{C}$. By the Yoneda lemma, we know that natural transformations from $\mathcal{C}(A,–)$ to $F$ are in one-to-one correspondence with the elements of $F A$.

According to this Wikipedia [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representable_functor#Universal_elements), the natural transformation induced by an element $u \in F A$ is an isomorphism if and only if $(A,u)$ is a *universal element* of $F$. A *universal element* of a functor $F : \mathcal{C} \rightarrow \mathcal{Set}$ is a pair $(A,u)$ consisting of an object $A$ of $\mathcal{C}$ and an element $u \in F A$ such that for every pair $(X,v)$ with $v \in F X$ there exists a unique morphism $f : A \rightarrow X$ such that $(F f)\ u = v$.

If the natural transformation induced by $u \in F A$ is indeed an isomorphism, is this due to the uniqueness property of the morphism $f : A → X$?

To clarfiy, in my head, we have:

$$α_X : \mathcal{C}(A,X) \rightarrow F X\\
α_X (f) = (F f)\ u$$

and we need to define the inverse of $α_X$, call it $β_X : F X → \mathcal{C}(A,X)$, but this can only be defined if $α_X$ is injective (i.e., $f$ satisfying the above equation is unique). Is this correct?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that under the prescription of $\alpha_X$ in your question the following statements are equivalent:

- for **every** $v\in FX$ there is **unique** $f\in\mathcal C(A,X)$ such that $(Ff)(u)=v$.
- for **every** $v\in FX$ there is **unique** $f\in\mathcal C(A,X)$ such that $\alpha_X(f)=v$.
- function $\alpha_X:\mathcal C(A,X)\to FX$ is bijective.

Here **every** corresponds with surjectivity and **unique** with injectivity.

Does this make things more clear for you?

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are very welcome.